# Default value for TextBoxFor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In ASP.NET MVC, I wrote below code to give the textbox a initial value:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.WEIGHT, new { tabindex = "140", 
                                      @class = "mustInputText noime  w50", 
                                      maxlength = "8", @Value = "0", 
                                      rule = "InputOnlyNum" })
```

And the Html source is as follows:

```
<input Value="0" class="mustInputText noime  w50" id="WEIGHT" maxlength="8" 
    name="WEIGHT" rule="InputOnlyNum" tabindex="140" type="text" value="" />
```

I notices that there are two Value attributes in the "input" tag:
`Value="0"` and  `value=""`

How to make it only show one value attribute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use TextBox instead of TextBoxFor

```
@Html.TextBox("WEIGHT", Model.WEIGHT ?? "0", new {...})
```

or if WEIGHT is an empty string

```
@Html.TextBox("WEIGHT", Model.WEIGHT == "" ? "0" : Model.WEIGHT, new {...})
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be the default behavior. If you really want to avoid the double Value attributes, it's better to follow the cleaner way by setting the default value in the create method of the controller class. This follows the ideology of the MVC pattern.

```
//GET
public ActionResult CreateNewEntity()
{
    YourEntity newEntity= new YourEntity ();
    newEntity.WEIGHT= 0;

    return View(newEntity);
}
```

Then on your view, you won't need to use the value attribute anymore:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.WEIGHT, new { tabindex = "140", 
                                      @class = "mustInputText noime  w50",     
                                      maxlength = "8", 
                                      rule = "InputOnlyNum" })
```

Your resulting html is:

```
<input class="mustInputText noime  w50" 
       id="WEIGHT" 
       maxlength="8" 
       name="WEIGHT" 
       rule="InputOnlyNum" 
       tabindex="140" 
       type="text" 
       value="0" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Well you've explicitly stated `Value`, not `value`.

Try:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.WEIGHT, new { tabindex = "140", @class = "mustInputText noime  w50", maxlength = "8", @value = "0", rule = "InputOnlyNum" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but try `TextBox` instead of `TextBoxFor`, as it has an overload for passing the value as the second parameter.

```
@Html.TextBox(p => p.WEIGHT, "0",
    new { tabindex = "140", @class = "mustInputText noime  w50", 
          maxlength = "8", @Value = "0", rule = "InputOnlyNum" })
```

The other option is to set defaults in the constructor of the model class that initializes WEIGHT.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this? Untested.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => (p.WEIGHT==null ? 0 : p.WEIGHT), new { tabindex = "140", 
      @class = "mustInputText noime  w50", 
      maxlength = "8",  
      rule = "InputOnlyNum" })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.WEIGHT, new { tabindex = "140", @class = "mustInputText noime  w50", maxlength = "8",
 @value =  model.WEIGHT==null?"0":model.WEIGHT, rule = "InputOnlyNum" })
```