# How to set Default value in textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Age, new{ @value="0" })

public Nullable<decimal> Age { get; set; }
```

When default value set this method but value not set value why

Comment: look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414012/default-value-for-textboxfor-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: use this code also bu not set when property change int type then default value set but  i can't change  property type

Comment: Never set value attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods! Set the value of property `Age` in the controller GET method before you pass the model to the view

Comment: Done But why value not set as use of attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Value` `V` should be capital

```
@html.TextBoxFor(Model=>Model.Age,new{@Value="0"})
```

Comment: But Edit time If Property have Same Some Value Like 20 then Value Should Be auto 0 because Attribute value set 0 So all Time Value Should Be Zero

Comment: If you are assigning it from code behind you can do it like this `@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model .Age, new {@Value = Age`})` @Krishna Soni

Comment: If you want `0` set `0` in `Age` and any other value which you want to display.

Comment: **NEVER** set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods! Your set the value of the property in the GET method before you pass the model to the view.